# Enable remote control in custom TV launcher in Android

Tags: android, android-launcher, television

I faced problem in my custom tv launcher in android.

I have created a custom android launcher for oneNuts device for tv and installed the launcher for it. I have used mouse or remote control to act with device. When using mouse there is no problem, the launcher work perfectly, but when using remote control, it does not work.

Comment: Please provide more details on your question, what you have tries to solve it or what has caused the problem.

Comment: Hi Ali , Thank you for you responding . I create custom android launcher for oneNuts device for TV when install the launcher int it . I use mouse or remote control to act with device when using mouse there is no problem the launcher work perfectly but when using remote control it not working exactly remote control not clicked on button inside launcher . Hope help me .